# Localhost/ is missing

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I have my wampServer running on my laptop. I can access localhost without problem. 
But everytime I access a folder "myProject" for example in the localhost, I get this path `myProject` and it doesn't work. I must add every time the word `localhost/` before the path so that it works.

Does anyone please know how can I change settings in wampserver so that it can access all projects by adding `/localhost`by default.

I don't know if I've well descriped the issue, but I'm ready to provide any screen shots needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your www folder open index.php at line 30
2. Change: $suppress_localhost into `false`. It should look like this:

   ```
   $suppress_localhost = false;
   ```

Comment: Thank  you so much :)

Comment: Correct solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Or if you want to use this bad solution, there is a menu item that will do this `left click wampmanager->Wamp Settings->add localhost in url`